# Does LockSupport.park method release lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource?

Tags: java, multithreading

As method Thread.suspend javadoc says

> This method has been deprecated, as it is inherently deadlock-prone. If the target thread holds a lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource when it is suspended, no thread can access this resource until the target thread is resumed. If the thread that would resume the target thread attempts to lock this monitor prior to calling resume, deadlock results.

and class LockSupport javadoc says

> Methods park and unpark provide efficient means of blocking and unblocking threads that do not encounter the problems that cause the deprecated methods Thread.suspend and Thread.resume to be unusable for such purposes: Races between one thread invoking park and another thread trying to unpark it will preserve liveness, due to the permit.

I'm not good at English,I can't understand difference between Thread.suspend and LockSupport.park？And does LockSupport.park method release lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource?

Comment: TL;DR LockSupport's park/unpark methods does not use monitor locks.